# Bootstrap Navbar collapsing into a neat list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to implement a Bootstrap Navbar that would collapse into a stack. I mainly managed to make it work, but I'm having a small issue with the way collapsed menu items are placed:

Uncollapsed menu:
[image]

Collapsed menu, where items are awkwardly placed:
[image]

Here my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Menu</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item mr-sm-2">
                    <select class="custom-select" id ="first">
                        <option value="1">Menu entry 1</option>
                        <option value="0">Menu entry 2</option>
                        <option value="2">Menu entry 3</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item mr-sm-2">
                    <select class="custom-select" id ="second">
                        <option value="a">Menu entry A</option>
                        <option value="b">Menu entry B</option>
                        <option value="c">Menu entry C</option>
                        <option value="d">Menu entry D</option>
                    </select>
                </li>
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="min." aria-label="varMin" id="varMin" size="16">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" placeholder="max." aria-label="varMax" id="varMax" size="16">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" id="envoyer" type="button">Envoyer</button>
            </form>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
```

How can I get the menu to collapse in a way that would show each menu item staked vertically (with a small space separation, similar to the spacing present in the uncollapsed, horizontal menu)?

Comment: It looks like something got moved — your form class is inside the unordered list (ul) and the list items (li) are inside the form. Move the form class line, the two inputs, the button, and the form close `</form>` to below the `</ul>` and it should collapse normally.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Although, I can't seem to make it work... Would you mind, if you have a minute, sending a pastebin with the solution? Or, better yet, writing a short answer so I can give you credits :)

Answer (score 0):

I moved the `form-inline` part to the bottom and left the list items in the list.

I also played a little with the sizing for the layout for smaller screens when the menu is dropped down.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    @media (min-width:576px) {
        .navbar-nav, .form-inline {
            width: 30rem;
        }
    }

    @media (min-width:992px) {
        .navbar-nav, .form-inline {
            width: auto;
        }
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item my-2 my-lg-0 mr-lg-2">
                <select class="custom-select" id="first">
                    <option value="1">Menu entry 1</option>
                    <option value="0">Menu entry 2</option>
                    <option value="2">Menu entry 3</option>
                </select>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item mr-lg-2">
                <select class="custom-select" id="second">
                    <option value="a">Menu entry A</option>
                    <option value="b">Menu entry B</option>
                    <option value="c">Menu entry C</option>
                    <option value="d">Menu entry D</option>
                </select>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-auto" placeholder="min." aria-label="varMin" id="varMin" size="16" style="width: 12rem;">
            <input class="form-control mr-auto" placeholder="max." aria-label="varMax" id="varMax" size="16" style="width: 12rem;">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-lg-0" id="envoyer" type="button">Envoyer</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```